# how to get data into view from controller in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

```
$this->loadModel('Siteconfig');

$data=$this->Siteconfig->find('all');

foreach($data as $data)
{           
    $email=$data['Siteconfig']['email'];

    $companyname=$data['Siteconfig']['companyname'];

    $cfa=$data['Siteconfig']['cfa'];
}
```

Above is **Controller**

How to get **cfa** data in view using **CAKEPHP?**

Comment: `foreach($data as $data)` isn't valid. You need to use a different variable to represent each item in the `$data` array. And after you fix that,  `$email`, `$companyname`, and `$cfa` are going to be overwritten in each iteration of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller method, you can use this

```
$this->set('var_name_in_view', $cfa);  //You will find the variable $cfa as $var_name_in_view in your view(You have to use $var_name_in_view in view)
```

You can also send multiple variables to your view at once

```
$this->set(compact('cfa', 'another_variable'));  //You can acceess using $cfa and $another_variable
```

> Compact makes an array keeping the variable name as key and variable value as the value for the array key.

Comment: Tried the same shows error Notice (8): Undefined variable: cfa [APP/View/Shipment/add.ctp, line 306]

Comment: Variables inside the compact must be same as the variable name(only excluding the $ sign). The error may be because If you $data will null then $cfa will be undefined so that the error is causing. I have changed in your question please have a look. @Mohamed

Answer (score 0):

Modify your script to

```
$this->loadModel('Siteconfig');

$data=$this->Siteconfig->find('all');
$cfa = '';

foreach($data as $datum)
{           
    $email=$datum['Siteconfig']['email'];

    $companyname=$datum['Siteconfig']['companyname'];

    $cfa=$datum['Siteconfig']['cfa'];
}
$this->set('view_cfa',$cfa);
```

This will fix it. Your foreach was reassigning $data.

Comment: Tried the same shows error Notice (8): Undefined variable: cfa [APP/View/Shipment/add.ctp, line 306] –

Comment: I modified the answer , check it now.